# text file manipulation with complex cell entries (AWK? Python?)

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
Chr1 29901 C T 0/0:0,21,143:7:36 0/0:0,3,35:21:18 0/0:0,123,188:41:99 1/0:23,188,12:41:99 1/1:184,75,0:25:54 
Chr1 32101 A G 1/0:23,188,12:41:99 1/1:184,75,0:25:54, 0/0:0,21,143:7:36 0/0:0,3,35:21:18 0/0:0,123,188:41:99 
…
```

Where there are 4 columns of general information, then many columns (samples) coded like  `0/0:0,21,143:7:36`

For each cell of the samples, I would like to determine if the last two numbers of the cell (separated by a colon) meet two criteria. The first number must be greater than 19, and the second must be greater than 29 (i.e. `:>19:>29`).

If both of these criteria are not met, I’d like to replace the cell with an `X`. If both these criteria are met, then for each row, I’d like to replace the cell with two letters that relate the first part of the cell entry (`0/0`, `0/1`, or `1/1`) to the values in the third and fourth columns. If 0, then use the value from the third column, if 1, then use the value from the fourth column.

Applying these criteria and manipulations, I’d like to end up with something like this:

```
Chr1 29901 C T X X CC TC TT
Chr1 32101 A G GA GG X X AA
```

Can anyone offer some advice on how to (easily) go about doing this (particularly using awk or python)?

Comment: Added the [tag:bash] tag since I presume this is in a bash shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good job for awk.

```
awk '
{
  for (i = 5; i <= NF; ++i) {
    split($i, a, ":");
    $i = (a[3] < 20 || a[4] < 30) ? "X" : $(3+substr(a[1],1,1)) $(3+substr(a[1],3,1));
  }
}
1
' file
```

**Explanation**

```
{
  # Loop through field numbers from 5 to the number of fields
  for (i = 5; i <= NF; ++i) {

    # Split field number i on ":" into array a
    split($i, a, ":");

         # If a[3] < 20 or a[4] < 30 then
    $i = (a[3] < 20 || a[4] < 30) ?

         # Set field i to "X"
         "X" :

         # Otherwise set it to the value of
         # field number (3 + int value of first char of a[1])
         # concatenated with the value of
         # field number (3 + int value of third char of a[1])
         $(3+substr(a[1],1,1)) $(3+substr(a[1],3,1));
  }
}

# The following condition is true, so execute default action, printing the record
1
```

Comment: +1: You can avoid using `printf` by just re-constructing your field as you iterate and print the line by using the `1` idiom... Nice logic though.

Comment: Thank you ooga. I am working my way through a book on awk now, just not quite there yet. I will try this out.

Comment: ooga - This almost works, but in come cells I get .. and in others I get something like .C I'm trying to play around with it to see what the issue might be. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @user2903950 Not sure what you're saying. Could you edit your question and add a couple of lines that do that?

Comment: @jaypal Thanks for the great tips. I've just heard about the `1` idiom and didn't think about reconstructing the fields. See edit. Thanks again!

Comment: @ooga Thanks for revising the answer. The `substr` logic was great and the use of ternary op just makes this solution immaculate! `;)`.

Comment: @ooga My mistake, text file was more complicated than my example, got it now thanks.

Comment: @ooga & jaypal With the revised version I'm getting an error message: awk: syntax error at source line 6
 context is
     $i = (a[3] < 20 || a[4] < 30)? >>> 
 <<< any ideas where I am gong wrong? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @user2903950 Your awk (apparently not gnu awk) probably doesn't allow the conditional operator to be split across lines. Try the edit above that puts it all on one line.